# Get user and roles from different servers at Spring Security

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security

I have an application that uses a LDAP server to authenticate. It works fine. But, there is a problem: in this LDAP server, I don't have the user roles. I have them in another server, in a database my application access. And I need to add the user roles to the application from now on.

I'd like to know how to get those roles and add them to the AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth at configureGlobal method. Is it possible?

Some information:

My configureGlobal method is:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter("uid={0}").contextSource().url(host);
}
```

I'm using hibernate 4.3.8 and Spring Security 4.1.1.

The table with the roles was created like this:

```
create table UserGroup (
    user varchar2(250),
    role varchar2(250)
);
```

And the records are something like this:

[user1, role1]

[user1, role2]

[user1, role3]

[user1, role4]

[user2, role1]

[user2, role2]

As you can see, the same user can have more than one role. The same role can be assigned to many users. I know it needs normalization, but I think that's not important at this point.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is implement a `UserDetailsService` that populates the user name and roles from the application's database & `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` that does an LDAP bind check inside `additionalAuthenticationChecks`.

Works like a charm.

In fact, the `UserDetails` contains a flag that tells me where to validate the user and inside the `additionalAuthenticationChecks`, we validated the user against one of multiple validation sources, such as the local database, or various multi-tenant LDAP servers.